# Make LINQ source update when source changes

Tags: c#, linq, windows-runtime

I have the following LINQ query that creates the source for a grouped `CollectionViewSource`. The problem is that it does not get updated when Examples changes (i.e. examples were added).
And I don't know how I can bind a LINQ query.

```
cvsExamplesSource.Source = from example in Examples
                           group example by example.Author into grp
                           orderby grp.Key
                           select grp;
```

So, how do I tell it to update whenever Examples changes without having to reload the entire source whenever a `PropertyChanged` Event occurs?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to bind **cvsExamplesSource.Source** in XAML with a new property ExamplesGrouped as shown:

**XAML:**

```
<SomeList x:Name="cvsExamplesSource" Source="{Binding ExamplesGrouped}"/>
```

**Data context class:**

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged /*or derive from ModelViewBase*/
{
    public ObservableCollection<Example> Examples { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Example>> ExamplesGrouped
    {
        get
        {
            return from example in Examples
                        group example by example.Author into grp
                        orderby grp.Key
                        select grp; 
        }
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Examples = new ObservableCollection<Example>();
        Examples.CollectionChanged += (_, __) => RaisePropertyChanged("ExamplesGrouped");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (null != handler)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```